# Return Statement not Working with continue

Tags: powershell, logonserver

**Update**

I was able to resolve this by changing `Rename-Item` to `Move-Item` and just changing the name in the process. However, this does not solve the mystery of why the `return` statement was not executed, or at least if it was, why the function continued to call `New-Item`.

---

I am trying to rename an item at logon, but if the item doesn't exist, I want to create it. Here is the function which does this:

```
function SelfHelpAppData {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    trap {Log-Error $_ $MyInvocation.MyCommand; Continue}

    $files = Get-ChildItem $AppData

    ForEach ($file in $files) {
        If ($file.Name -match 'qxjz') {

            Rename-Item $file.PSPath "qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -Force
            WriteLogonEntryData
            return
        }
    }

    New-Item "$AppData\qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt"
    WriteLogonEntryData
}
```

However, when this runs, I am receiving these errors in my log:

> Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.

> At \DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\mainlogon.ps1:841 char:5

- ```
  New-Item "$AppData\qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt"
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

And then:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

> At \DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\mainlogon.ps1:835 char:13

- ```
          Rename-Item $file.PSPath "qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -Force
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

But this is impossible, as if the first line (rename-item) attempted to run, then the function should have returned before the other line had a chance. I have tried changing the return statement to `return $null` but with no effect. Does anyone know what is going on here?

---

Here is the Log-Error code:

```
function Log-Error {
    param (
        $error,
        [string]$sub
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    trap {Log-Error $_ $MyInvocation.MyCommand; Continue}

    $filename = "\\file\administration\Unused\LogonScriptErrors\$env:USERNAME - $env:COMPUTERNAME - $(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy-HHmmss) - $($error.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber).log"

    New-Item $filename -ItemType File -Value "$($error.Exception.Message) `r`n `r`n $($error.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage) `r`n `r`n $sub"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behavior you observed is the `continue` in your `trap` statement list. It causes the script to continue with the next instruction after the loop where the error occurred. This is [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) behavior.

If you want the script to terminate operation in case of an error remove the `continue`. If you want it just exit from the function change `continue` to `return`.

With that said, I'd recommend to move away from `trap` and use `try`/`catch` instead, which offers better control, even visually.

BTW, the `New-Item` error occurs, because you omitted the mandatory parameter `-Type`. Without that parameter the cmdlet tries to prompt you for the required information, but can't because the script is run non-interactively. To get rid of the error add `-Type File` to the statement.

Comment: beat me to it! Hopefully my example fits the situation appropriately.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks! I changed the traps inside my functions to `Return`, and kept the ones which were outside in the main body of the script as `Continue`. I find `trap` to look a lot cleaner, but you're right using `try/catch` would give me more control

Answer (score 1):

The PS error trap is being thrown every time because Error Action handling in powershell is a lot more "loose" than traditional Exception handling. Some revisions I made:

- Instead of doing a global blanket trap, use try/catch.
- Use `-Force` on both your new-item and rename-item statements.
- You forgot the `$env:` in `$env:AppData`
- You can get around the console verbage with `| Out-Null`

For the most part, doing individual try/catch error handling is tedious and ugly, which is probably why you went with `trap{}`. You can just do general exception handling with match cases instead if you **really** need that level of error handling with simple rename/create file operations.

```
function Do-Stuff {

    $EAPREF = 'Stop'
    $FILES = gci $env:APPDATA

    try {
        ForEach ($file in $FILES) {
            If ($file.Name -match 'qxjz') {
            Rename-Item $file.PSPath "qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -Force -ErrorAction $EAPREF | Out-Null
            return
            }
        }
        New-Item "$env:AppData\qxjz$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt" -ItemType 'File'  -Force -ErrorAction $EAPREF | Out-Null
    } 
    catch [System.Exception]{
        #Error handling here using type/parameter qualifier cases.

        if ($_.FullName -eq 'So and So'){
            # Handle the error a certain way for so-and-so
        }

        if ($_.FullName -eq 'Other exception type you expect'){
            # Handle another type of error separately
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly why I went with trap - it looks so much better. As this is for a logon script I just need to log every error/exception that I can in a file on the network. I'm not sure if there is a chance that using try/catch as you mentioned means I could potentially miss some (by not specifying all the possible `.fullnames`) but that was my thinking initially! Also, as every error is handle in the exact same way (write to a file) it seemed unnecessary to add loads of checks!